# PACT.io: Getting Missing requests error with pact test

Tags: angular, typescript, pact

I am running a simple pact test and it is giving the error of missing request. I fail to understand what am I missing in the test file.
Pact test:

```
describe('The drag and drop API', () => { 

 beforeAll(async () => {
    provider = new PactWeb({
      port: 1234,
      host: '127.0.0.1',
    });

    await setTimeout(() => {}, 2000);
    await provider.removeInteractions();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        DragNDropService,
        { provide: UserService, useClass: UserServiceMock },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: PactInterceptorService, multi: true },
      ],
    });
  });

  afterAll(async () => await provider.finalize());
  afterEach(async () => await provider.verify());

  describe('POST /objects/' + mockTopicId + '/record/', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
      const interaction = new Interaction()
        .given('I have a topic')
        .uponReceiving('a request to link a record')
        .withRequest({
          method: 'POST',
          path: '/api/objects/' + mockTopicId + '/record/',
          headers: {
            Authorization: bearerToken,
          },
          body: {
            id: mockObjectId,
          },
        })
    .willRespondWith({
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },
      body: true,
    });
      await provider.addInteraction(interaction);
    });

    it('returns the correct response', async () => {
      const dndService: DragNDropService = TestBed.inject(DragNDropService);    
      dndService.linkObjectToPL(mockTopicId, mockObjectId).subscribe(response => {
        expect(response).not.toBeNull();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and the service

```
  linkObjectToPL(topicId: string, objectId: string, recordId?: string) {
    return this.httpClient
      .post(`objects/${encodeURIComponent(topicId)}/record/`, {
        id: objectId,
        destRecordId: recordId,
      })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('linkObjectToPl')))
      .pipe(take(1));
  }
```

and the error I am getting is:

Error: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.
Missing requests:
POST /api/objects/tt/record/

Answer (score 0):

The error means the mock server setup by Pact given your contract definition expected to be called on  `/api/objects/tt/record/` as defined in the contract but your actual code never made such a call.

You have a `/api` missing in the actual code. Or is it to be removed in the contract.